# Getting a list of folders in base directory for Google Drive iOS in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, google-drive-api, google-signin

Using GoogleSignIn and GoogleAPIClientForREST, I've been able to sign in to google and even get a list of files just fine using code taken from the [Google Drive iOS quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ios?ver=swift). Really what I don't understand is how to filter out results from the request by file type, or really how to get contents of a subfolder. [Google Drive REST documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/) hasn't helped at all.

To clarify the issue: while

```
let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()

query.pageSize = 10

service.executeQuery(query,
                             delegate: self,
                             didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
```

works perfectly with

```
func displayResultWithTicket(ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
                             finishedWithObject result : GTLRDrive_FileList,
                             error : NSError?) {

    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    var text = "";

    if let files = result.files, !files.isEmpty {

        text += "Files:\n"
        for file in files {
            text += "\(file.name!) (\(file.identifier!))\n"
        }
    } else {
        text += "No files found."
    }
    print(text)
}
```

, I have no idea how to get only the folders or how to get files in a subfolder.

Comment: I'm really now sure why I've received negative points for this question. It's a valid question, correctly tagged. I did not supply a code supplement because as I stated, the code I've been using is from the quickstart. Please, if you're going to leave a downvote, at least tell me why so I can make a more positive impact on this community.

Comment: did you find any solution for this. i am also stuck with this?. @connor24601

Comment: Sadly I have not yet found any good resource for learning the google drive API in swift. @Sreejiths I'll let you know if I find out, let me know if you find anything. Sadly, this post is still negative and rather old, so I doubt it'll ever get answered. I think perhaps the answer lies in making http requests within swift, which I also don't know.

Comment: hi did you find solution. If needed let me know. I found the solution. :)

Comment: Hey, I'd love the solution! if you can post an example, that'd be super helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Listing Folders we want to Declare the mimeType Just Like this

```
  let root = "(mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' or mimeType = 'image/jpeg' or mimeType = 'image/png' or mimeType = 'application/pdf' or mimeType = 'application/epub' or mimeType = 'application/msword' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') and '\(root)' in parents and trashed=false"
```

Now you can pass this root for list only your required needs

```
func GoogleDrivelistFiles(root : String) { //root 
    let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
    query.pageSize = 100
    query.q = root
    query.fields = "files(id,name,mimeType,modifiedTime,createdTime,fileExtension,size,parents,kind),nextPageToken"
    service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket, files, error) in
        if let filesList : GTLRDrive_FileList = files as? GTLRDrive_FileList {

            var cloudArray = Array<FileObject>()
            if let filesShow : [GTLRDrive_File] = filesList.files {
                for Array in filesShow {
                    let name = Array.name
                    let mimeType = Array.mimeType
                    let id = Array.identifier
                    let folder = (mimeType as NSString?)?.pathExtension
                    let isfolder = true
                    let parents = Array.parents
                    var parentPath : String!
                    for arrayParents in parents! {
                        parentPath = arrayParents
                    }

                    let creationTime = Array.createdTime?.date
                    let modifiedTime = Array.modifiedTime?.date
                    let fileSize : Int!
                    let fileExtension : String!
                    if isfolder == true {
                        fileSize = 0
                        fileExtension = "Folder"
                    }else {
                        fileSize = Array.size?.intValue
                        fileExtension = Array.fileExtension
                    }
                    if folder == "folder" {
                    let content = FileObject(path: mimeType!, isFolder: true, parentPath: parentPath!, fileName: name!, creationDate: creationTime!, lastModified: modifiedTime!, fileSize: fileSize!, fileExtension: fileExtension!, fileId: id!, isSyncing: true)
                    cloudArray.append(content)
                    } else {
                        let content = FileObject(path: mimeType!, isFolder: false, parentPath: parentPath!, fileName: name!, creationDate: creationTime!, lastModified: modifiedTime!, fileSize: fileSize!, fileExtension: fileExtension!, fileId: id!, isSyncing: true)
                        cloudArray.append(content)
                    }
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.delegate?.DataRefresh(fileObject: cloudArray)
            }

        }else {

        }
    })
}
```

For getting the subFolder also you can write on didSelectTable and you want to pass this root to the same func GoogleDriveListFiles().

```
//ForGeting SubFolders//
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let FolderId = array[indexpath.row].id
 //important step
 let FolderIdroot = "(mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' or mimeType = 'image/jpeg' or mimeType = 'image/png' or mimeType = 'application/pdf' or mimeType = 'application/epub' or mimeType = 'application/msword' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') and '\(FolderId)' in parents and trashed=false"

  //now you can call that fun which I have already written for listingFiles func GoogleDrivelistFiles(root :String)//

   GoogleDrivelistFiles(root : FolderIdRoot)
 }
```

Comment: can you give the code after selecting the folder? How would i get the list of the files within a folder?

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala Hope you will understand what I have written. :) happy coding

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala did you get my point please tell the review :)

Comment: yes, I was thinking what about folders but the list is giving a merged result of both of them. :) Thank you for second section code.

Comment: This gives me `GTLRDrive_FileList 0x281af3f90: {files:[0]}`. Although I have folders in my drive. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can get all the folder list using below function:-

```
func getAllfolders() {

   let root = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"

   let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
   query.pageSize = 100
   query.q = root
   query.fields = "files(id,name,mimeType,modifiedTime,createdTime,fileExtension,size),nextPageToken"

   service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket, files, error) in

       if let filesList : GTLRDrive_FileList = files as? GTLRDrive_FileList {
           if let filesShow : [GTLRDrive_File] = filesList.files {
               print("files \(filesShow)")
               for ArrayList in filesShow {
                   let name = ArrayList.name ?? ""
                   let id = ArrayList.identifier ?? ""
                   print("hello\(name)", id)
               }
           }
       }
   })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the folder list including/excluding trashed folders:-

```
func getAllfolders() {

   let root = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'" // including trash folder or add and trashed=true
   //let root = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false" // excluding trash folders
   let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
   query.pageSize = 100
   query.q = root
   query.fields = "files(id,name,mimeType,modifiedTime,createdTime,fileExtension,size),nextPageToken"

   service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: {(ticket, files, error) in

       if let filesList : GTLRDrive_FileList = files as? GTLRDrive_FileList {
           if let filesShow : [GTLRDrive_File] = filesList.files {
               print("files \(filesShow)")
               for ArrayList in filesShow {
                   let name = ArrayList.name ?? ""
                   let id = ArrayList.identifier ?? ""
                   print("hello\(name)", id)
               }
           }
       }
   })
 }
```